# JavaScript execution stops when I get the URL with window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an online shop as part of an exercise and I have an issue when I try to access the current URL's parameters. My JavaScript code is:

```
var link = getQueryVariable("q");
var minPrice = 0;
var maxPrice = 500;

function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
           var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
           var vars = query.split("&");
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable){
                       return pair[1];
                    }
           }
           return(false);
    }
    function setPrices(callback){
        $.get("getPriceBounds.php?q=" + link, function(data){
            var results = JSON.parse(data);
            minPrice = results["min"];
            maxPrice = results["max"];  
            callback();
        },"text/javascript");
    }
```

Do I use window.location in the wrong way or there is another way to access the URL without stoping the execution?

Thank you

Comment: Look in the browser's JavaScript console. Do you see errors there?

Comment: Most likely `window.location.search` is undefined.

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to find out the value of for example ?v=10&t=1 right? (So what would be $_GET in PHP)

Comment: There is a small error which did not affect my initial question. I should pass q as a string and not as a variable.

Comment: @ChrisLear It's never `undefined` -> https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-search

Comment: @LJa this is a good suggestion. I will try it and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @ggeo I am not sure what you ment by that. My question was if getQueryVariable() tries to get the value of a parameter of from your url? So if your url would be index.html?p=10, it tries to get the 10 out of the url?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the correction. Please ignore my original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Use this instead. If you were on the page **http://example.org/index.html?q=300** and do:

```
var q = getParameterByName("q");
console.log(q);
```

Then 300 will be printed in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Using window.location.search should work absolutely fine.

You could try the following alternative for getting query parameters in case there is something not quite right with the code.

```js
var q = 'myParam';

var getParams = function(url) {
  return (window.location.search || url).slice(1).split('&')
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      b = b.split('=');
      a[b[0]] = b[1];
      return a;
    }, {});
}

getParams(); //{}
getParams('?test=7&more=test'); //{test:7, more:'test'}
```

NB: The above code won't run in the embedded snippet runner because it does not have a window object.